# Is it possible for AWS Lambda to have more than one trigger?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I have created a .Net application with AWS serverless application template. When I deploy it I have a Lambda with API Gateway trigger (let's call is A)

When A gets a GET/POST request, it delegates the work to a worker lambda (let's call it B). When B finishes the work, it publishes a message to an SNS topic.

The lambda A needs to subscribe to the SNS topic for it to know if the work is completed or not.

I am able to add an SNS trigger to the lambda A (in addition to the API Gateway trigger). But I don't know how to use the trigger in the .Net application. It would be great if anyone throws some light on how to implement the function handler when API Gateway and SNS triggers are added to the same lambda.

Comment: Why do you want the function triggered from both API Gateway _and_ SNS? Are you wanting Function A to wait for the result of Function B before returning the result to API Gateway?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, yes, you are correct. Function A waits for the result of function B before returning the result to API Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your flow is:

```
User --> API Gateway --> Lambda A --> Lambda B
```

If you want Lambda function A to receive a result from Lambda function B, it should simply do a synchronous `Invoke()` API call on Lambda Function B. Whatever value that is returned by Function B will then be returned to Function A. There is **no need to use Amazon SNS in the response**.

It's worth mentioning that you will be paying for both functions, since Function A will be 'running' while it is waiting for Function B. Therefore, you might want to combine both operations into a single function to avoid being double-charged for the time.

There is no concept of re-triggering the original Function A -- once it finishes execution, the function context is lost. Your plan of using SNS to call Function A would simply be starting *another* execution of Function A, rather than 'calling back' to the original function.

Answer (score 0):

I see that I can update the CFT to add more than one trigger type. But in C# code, FunctionHandler method is not generic and it is specific to one trigger type. So I don't see a way to handle more than one trigger type in C#.